# como poner la validacion

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

En este popup tengo que extraer la informacion por nombre y fecha pero no se si esta bien las validaciones que puse ya que los nombres estan guardados en el campo seller_id pero cuando ewn la vista del popup enla ointerfaz de odoo manda un error cuando descargo el reporte y dice qu ela validacion esta mal

Adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
import calendar
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from dateutil import rrule

from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import delta
from xlsxwriter import workbook

from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api


try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
 except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_executive"

date_order = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
seller_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee',string='Ejecutivo')
def get_executive_report(self):
    data = {
        'date_order': self.date_order,
        'seller_id': self.seller_id,
    }
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_ejecutivo_report').report_action(self, data=data)


 class executivecard(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.sale_report_terrestre.sales_executive_view'

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    return {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'sale.order',
        'docs': self.env['sale.order'].search_read([('date_order', '>=', data['date_order']),
                                                    ('seller_id', '==', data['seller_id'])],
                                                   ['name', 'seller_id','date_order', 'consignee_id', 'country_arrival', "freight_type", "gross_weight", "volume","invoice_amount_assured"])

    }
```

Asi es como tengo estrcturada la abstraccion pero en la segunda validacion de seller_id es donde esta mandando el error que puedo hacer ahi para corregir ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese error da cuando descargo el reporte

Comment: Por favor, recuerda poner las trazas de los errores como texto.

Comment: lo intente como pusiste en la repuesta y manda el informe vacio @Legna

Comment: de la unica forma que imprime el informe lleno es cuando lo pongo asi  ('seller_id', '!=', data['seller_id']) @Legna pero me imprime todos los registros de todos los usuario y tengo que hacer que imprima de cada usuario no de todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los dominios, para representar igualdad, se utiliza `'='` en lugar de `'=='`. No es que la validación este mal, más bien es diferente de como se hace normalmente en python.

Deberia ser así:

```
('seller_id','=','el_otro_dato_de_hr')
```

Comment: de echo lo intente asi porque lo que va  hacer es que el seller_id que se seleccione debe de ser el mismo que esta esta en data por ejemp`lo quiero que me m uezstre las cotizaciones que esten solo con mi nombre y segun esto es si el seller id es igual al que se mete a la busqueda e imprime en el reporte la informacion que tenga m9i nombre pero no se como ponerlo asi en el modelo

Comment: porque lo estuve intentando ponerlo como diferente y es donde me imprime todos los registros cuando con mi nombre de usuario de odoo solo tengo 2

Comment: porque ya lo ahbia intentado asi como lo pusiste en la respuesta y manda el reporte vacio que podria hacer ahi? @Legna